# Routing doesn't work properly if there are query parameters in the path

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, tabview

I've got a component with tab view (`p-tabView`) with several tabs where I have implemented routing by myself. I have noticed that when I navigate to a path like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['part1/part2', this.id]);
```

or like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['part1/part2']);
```

the navigation works fine and I can navigate between tabs this way.
However when I navigate with query parameters:

```
this.router.navigate(['part1/part2'],
    {queryParams: {'name': this.name, 'version': this.version}});
```

the url address in the browser changes but nothing happens on the page (content does not change, tab does not change). Also the tab view component is not being "entered" in this case. 
Is there maybe a problem in my routing module file?

```
export const myComponentRoutes = [
  {
    path: 'part1',
    data: {title: 'part1'},
    children: [
      {
        path: ':tab',
        component: MyTabviewComponent
      }
      ,
      {
        path: ':tab/:id',
        component: MyTabviewComponent
      }
    ]
  },
];
```

Comment: Are you reading the query params in MyTabviewComponent? Check in console for nulls or undefined values

Comment: I am, but the problem is that MyTabViewComponents doesn’t get hit at all when I navigate with query params

Comment: Can you enable tracing in router configuration, it might provide some usefule debug info https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#enableTracing